# I need help to translate error message with next-intl and zod

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem. I have setup next-intl which works but I don't understand how to make the translations work with zod schema

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import {TypeOf, object, string,} from "zod"
import { i18n } from 'next-i18next';

const passwordValidation = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/u

export const createUserSchema = object({
      firstName: string({required_error: "FirstName is required"}).min(
        1,
        "Firstname is required"
    )
        .max(32, "firstname must be less than 32 characters"),
    lastName: string({required_error: "Name is required"}).min(
        1,
        "Lastname is required"
    )
        .max(32, "lastname must be less than 32 characters"),
 
a response to help me , it's a project for school
```